# What do the different weapon damages imply?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

So far in my adventuring throughout the world of Kingdoms of Amalur, I've discovered several weapons with stats like:

> - +11 Physical Damage
> - +6 Piercing Damage

I realize that Physical damage is base damage, while piercing damage is damage that ignores the enemy's armor rating. What I'm wondering is:

**Are these two types of damage included separately?**

(i.e. +11 Physical, +6 Piercing for a total of 17 damage vs. +11 Physical damage, 6 of which ignores enemy armor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Like the Magic options, physical damage has "schools". Magic has Fire, Lightning, Poison, etc, and Martial has "Piercing", "Physical", etc.

These quantities are distinct.

```
+11 Physical
+11 Piercing
```

has twice the base damage of

```
+11 Piercing
```

[image: Here's a picture]

Comment: I assume that certain armor and/or enemies have resistances to these types of physical damage, like they might to elemental.

Comment: It's scary how much your character resembles mine. I think we even have the same tattoo.

Comment: @Tristan I actually got on your computer to take this picture. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Amalur, each type of damage is its own intra-specific species, basically. Physical damage is almost usually ever and always involved; beyond that, the cross-interactions are complicated (complexity a re-occurring thing in KoA, better or worse.)

The differences are interesting and not that horrible to mentally internalize for the sake of mindfully playing in the game's own world, even if sometimes eccentric-seeming...

The granitic underpinning base damage is Physical.

Piercing damage differs from Physical because it ignores armor (as you know; I am a loutish one) and even if only small percentage-wise in a certain weapon or attack, can thus prove useful against highly-armored or resilient foe types.

Bleeding damage is distinctive because bleeding damage weakens the totality of health and capacity to unleash damage of the enemy. An enemy capable of being affected by bleeding damage, is rendered weaker, its attacks become weaker and affected in this way, is roughly 30% more vulnerable to any Physical or Piercing damage output unleashed by the player; elemental damage has no interactivity here whatsoever... Again, peculiarities of the designers of the game, not necessarily alienating, just "different"...

Poison damage possesses a Damage-over-Time property (DOT) and even more than Bleeding, inhibits the offensive potential of the affected enemy. Any enemy not immune to Poison damage, suffering poisoning, necessarily will do approx. 30% less damage to the player, GLOBALLY.

Another type of damage "race" is the Stun-type. Stunned enemies are incapable of counter-attacking or reacting efficiently to attacks of the player for a very specific set period of time. In the game, certain attacks also inflict more (Physical and otherwise) damage when a specifically stunned foe is the target.

Fire damage is "elemental" (understandably) and possesses a DoT property and in certain cases, produces a so-called "Panic" effect or state, totally ceasing any attacks to the player...

In my experience, the most utile elemental damage type has been Ice damage. The enemy affected by Ice damage is slowed down by around 30% in terms of both basic movement and attack speed.

Lightning is another elemental sub-type of damage, and is mainly notable for its special tendency to "propagate" in the context of enemy groups. Technically, Lightning damage also causes a slightly stronger "Interrupt" effect than either Ice or Fire.

Gaining knowledge, via direct painful experience or otherwise, of which enemy sets are vulnerable to this or that Damage effect, is thus part of the equation here...

Again, this is their world, their creation... I don't find it that indigestible if perhaps not fully thought out...

About numbers, I myself once was purely intellectually interested in such questions, numbers, equations, etc., but I gave up at a certain point, simply humbling recognizing I did not fully understand, and/or the devs. also might not have understood what they were doing (?)...

Despite the zany esotericism of KoA, it overall is a masterpiece, my final thought here.

My estimations of certain percentages are based on my experience, so if I am off horribly, I apologize. I have good reasons to believe I am tolerably accurate (hopefully?).

The official guide book is something like 20 pounds, 1000 pages, and 500 dollars (or so I have heard), and I am but a proletarian nonentity...