# What are the numbers in the top-left of the weapon/armor stats display?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

This post talks about weapons and armor stats, but doesn't explain the numbers in the top-left corner of the display:

[What do the different weapon damages imply?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50017/what-do-the-different-weapon-damages-imply)

These numbers seem to be base quality levels, which is also represented by their name color (green, blue, purple, gold, etc).  Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the numbers you're referring to are the `xx/yy` numbers. Those numbers refer to the condition of the weapon/armor.

The `xx` part refers to the current condition of the item, which degrades with usage. Weapons degrade when they're used to attack and armor degrades when you receive damage from enemies. When an item's condition reaches 0 and it is used, it'll break and lose all its effectiveness. You'll either have to repair it at a blacksmith or use a repair kit.

The `yy` part refers to the maximum durability of the item.

Comment: Actually, I've had an item reach 0 and not break. It broke once *used* at 0 durability. Also, the mention of current durability reaching 0 and needing repair is closer in content to the description of current durability and might fit better in the previous paragraph. Also some mention of how durability relates to quality could be mentioned as that was asked.

Comment: @skovacs1, Thanks, I didn't know that.. :-).. I don't know how I placed that sentence in the wrong section, thanks for catching it. I've updated my answer.